# Sizing child elements of a container automatically (why is container_resize_children deprecated)

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3, deprecation-warning

I'm writing a system tray whose size is determined at runtime (and can possibly changed due to a resize), and I would like to size tray icons so that they expand to the size of the container object in which they are placed.

I have actually gotten this to work in the following way registering for the size allocated signal for the gtk_image widget, and assigning to it a pixbuf with a size that matches the height allocated to this image widget in provided callback function.

The only issue with this approach is that this does not seem to trigger a resize of the image widget (even if I explicitly call widget_set_size_request), which leads to this issue: [image: tray images overlap] Calls to widget_queue_draw or widget_queue_resize to both the image and the containing box do nothing to ameliorate this issue, but calling the deprecated function `gtk_container_resize_children` DOES fix the issue:
[image]

My questions are

- Why is gtk_container_resize_children deprecated?
- Is my approach of only actually setting the pixbuf for the image when the size allocate signal is received sound, or is there a better way of doing this?
- Why doesn't widget_queue_draw work here either?

You can find the actual code in question here, but it is written in haskell, so may be difficult to understand if you are not familiar with the language:

https://github.com/IvanMalison/gtk-sni-tray/blob/4e7750b2893dc3c6c0091355f3c9b42ab35dcdf2/src/StatusNotifier/Tray.hs#L166

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [implementation of `gtk_container_resize_children`](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/f5482e6954cb2aca70d14064ec28a3a38d1fd831/gtk/gtkcontainer.c#L2227), it seems you should be able to replace it with calls to [`gtk_widget_get_allocated_size`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-allocated-size) and [`gtk_widget_allocate_with_baseline`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-size-allocate-with-baseline), neither of which is deprecated in GTK+ 3.